# arrow keys console input ada95

Tags: input, keyboard, console, ada

Hello I am trying to monitor when the Up or down arrow key is pressed.

```
Ada.Text_IO.Get_Immediate(User_Input, Key_pressed);
        if Key_pressed then
            if User_Input = ???? then
                    null;
            end if;
        end if;
```

What do I check against to see that the key has been pressed.

I have checked the control characters in the Ada.Characters.Latin_1 library along with some googling with no luck.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Key presses are not ASCII input.  Procedures that input ASCII (or Latin-1) characters will not be able to read key-press information, unless your OS translates them to the old ANSI escape sequences (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), and in that case the keys will be represented as multiple characters, not single characters.  Barring that, Ada won't help you.  If GNAT or your compiler vendor doesn't have a library for this, you'll need to look for a third-party library or interface directly to OS routines or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, if you're willing to use SDL, apparently there's a function for reading scancodes: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/13693070/

One of the guys that's on freenode's #Ada IRC channel is working on (and IIUC almost finished) with a SDL binding here: https://github.com/Lucretia/sdlada